# How to calculate width of tree recursively?

Tags: python, recursion

I have a tree with data structure:

```
root: {
    children:[
        {children: [
            {children:[]}
        ]},
        {children: []}
    ]
}
```

Here is example of tree where the result should be 4(maximum width)

```
                  R
               /  |  \
              A   B  X
             / \ / \
            C  D E  F
                \
                 G
```

Comment: Or other way rather than recursion

Comment: I can't imagine doing it without recursion.  Have a `counter = defaultdict(int)`, and as you recurse down the tree, keep track of your depth and do counter[depth] += 1.  Then when you're done, `max(counter.values())`.

Comment: you should go with `level order traversal` where you will be maintaining level wise queue, you can check the max(len(queue)) and you will get the max_width

Answer (score 1):

To do this with recursion, you can make a helper function that returns the size of the current level and then the sums of sizes of children at each level as a sequence. Take the maximum of sizes from the sequence for output:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def max_tree_width(tree):
    def widths(tree):
        return len(tree), *map(sum, zip_longest(*map(widths, tree.values()), fillvalue=0))
    return max(widths(tree))
```

So that given the following input, adapted from the sample tree in your question:

```
tree = {
    'R': {
        'A': {
            'C': {},
            'D': {
                'G': {}
            }
        },
        'B': {
            'E': {},
            'F': {}
        },
        'X': {}
    }
}
```

`max_tree_width(tree)` would return: `4`

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/CarelessPutridAutocad

Answer (score 1):

This can of course be solved in several ways. But here is a variant that uses [tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion):

```
def width_calc(trees, maxwidth=0):                                             
    # trees should be a list of all subtrees at the current level, so if its a 
    # dict (as expected in the first call) it is wrapped in a list.            
    if type(trees) is dict:                                                    
        trees = [trees]                                                        
    # Get all subtrees at the current level                                    
    subtrees = [v for tree in trees for v in tree.values()]                    
    # If there is subtrees at the current level then recurse down one more     
    # level. Also calculate the maxwidth so far and send to the next level.    
    if subtrees:                                                               
        return width_calc(subtrees, max(maxwidth, len(subtrees)))              
    # There is no subtrees at this level so we reached the last leaves and the 
    # maxwith can be returned.                                                 
    return maxwidth
```

Using your tree data (implemented by [@blhsing in another anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74150543/42580)), the call `width_calc(tree)` would return `4`.